# Cannot find EFI directory: issue with grub-install

Tags: linux, grub

I was trying to rescue GRUB in Linux. I was able to login in the OS following this tutorial:

https://www.lisenet.com/2014/grub2-rescue-mode-error-unknown-filesystem/

I have to upgrade GRUB to fix the problem. However, when I run `grub-install`, I get an error:

```
$ grub-install /dev/sda
grub-install: error: cannot find EFI directory.
```

My file system contains `sda4`, `sda5`, and `sda6` for the EFI system, Linux swap, and Linux file system respectively.

I am not very experienced using mount or other commands.

Answer (score 39):

When you run **grub-install** by default it assumes the EFI system is mounted as /boot/efi

It depends on your distribution where EFI system is mounted and on some distributions it isn't mounted after boot.

First check if /boot/efi is mounted with

```
mount | grep /boot/efi
```

If that doesn't work first try the following to see if it is mounted elsewhere.

```
mount | grep /dev/[efi device]
```

If neither of those work do:

```
mount /dev/[efi device] /mnt
```

Now run:

```
grub-install --efi-directory=[efi dir]
grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg
```

where [efi dir] is either /boot/efi or /mnt and [efi device] is the device with the EFI system partition. If you don't know use the command `lsblk -o NAME,PARTTYPE,MOUNTPOINT | grep -i "C12A7328-F81F-11D2-BA4B-00A0C93EC93B"`

Comment: Thanks, In the `grub-install --efi-directory=/boot/EFI` as i chroot into `/mnt`.

Comment: Maybe stupid Q but I don't have an EFI dir. Where do I get one? I mean it is supposed to contain files, which command can recreate it?

Comment: @LennartRolland If you have a UEFI compatible system then your system drive will be GPT partitioned and contains a "UEFI System partition." usually the first partition and will be of the type EF00. Many distributions will mount this by default as /boot/efi to among other things allow the GRUB boot loader to update its files. If not you'll have to mount it yourself and add it to fstab. You might also have a UEFI system but that is using legacy mode which means your partitions will be msdos type and you won't have a /boot/efi. Weirder configurations exist but that covers the majority of them.

Comment: Your instructions if EFI is not mounted are wrong. See my edit. `mount | grep /dev/sda6` doesn't work. If EFI is not mounted, you have to check the partitions for type.

Comment: @giusti Probably better to just not make specific device name references.

Comment: @jdwolf when I typed"_mount | grep /dev/[efi device]_" I got "_grep: Unmatched [, [^, [:, [., or [=_"..... maybe a misspelling?

Comment: grub-install: error: install device isn't specified.

Comment: @jdwolf, what if I don't have EFI partition at all? Because I have deleted it...

Comment: Mounting `/mnt/boot/efi` and chrooting doesn't work. grub then complains about missing `/dev` in the chroot. OK, so `mount --bind /dev/ /mnt/dev` but then grub complains about other things. What did work was this: `grub-install -d /mnt/usr/lib/grub/x_86_64-efi --boot-directory=/mnt/boot /dev/sda`

Comment: Turns out I had 2 EFI partitions, and this `lsblk` filter helped me locate the correct partition and its UUID. I now have separate mount points and partitions for `/boot (sdb1)` and `/boot/efi (nvme0n1p2)`, and my `grub-install` problems are solved. I have also added an entry to `/etc/fstab` to mount this automatically: `UUID=10DB-B8A8    /boot/efi    vfat defaults 0 0`

Answer (score 11):

The efi directory must be in **/boot/efi/**

To know in which partition the efi is, we must examine the partition table, so if your main disk is /dev/sda then.

```
fdisk -l /dev/sda
Device             Start        End   Sectors   Size Type
/dev/sda1           2048     309247    307200   150M EFI System
/dev/sda2         309248  964843519 964534272 459.9G Linux filesystem
/dev/sda3      964843520 1000214527  35371008  16.9G Linux filesystem
```

In the result search for something like **EFI System** or **EFI (FAT-12/16/32)**

Once you know the partition number then (in this case sda1), we must mount it in **/boot/efi**.

If for some reason the directory /boot/efi/ does not exist, create it:

```
mkdir /boot/efi
```

and mount the efi into that directory:

```
mount /dev/sda1 /boot/efi/
```

And I think that is all, you must be able to install grub in your disk.

Comment: Note that grub is case-*sensitive* while the EFI filesystem is case-*preserving*.  If your boot directory is `/boot/EFI`, the UEFI firmware can find it, but grub can't.

Comment: @Mark also worth noting that you'll end up with `/boot/efi/EFI` once everything is correctly set up

Answer (score 7):

I just now encountered this issue. I booted a rescue USB stick. Let me describe the fix that worked for me.

Prowling around with `gdisk -l /dev/sda` I can see that my original root partition is `/dev/sda2`. To access it, I type `sudo mount /dev/sda2 /mnt`

So far, so good. Let me first describe what *didn't* work, and then a solution. Some pages advise `chroot /mnt` and then `grub-install`, but this won't work; giving the `grub-install: error: cannot find EFI directory.` error.

Following other suggestions, I see that my EFI partition is `/dev/sda1` so I try `sudo mount /dev/sda1 /mnt/boot/efi` and chroot again. Now, grub complains about missing `/dev` so I `mount --bind /dev/ /mnt/dev`. ... But then grub complains about something else. It's snowballing out of control. `chroot` is not the answer.

What did work was this: `grub-install -d /mnt/usr/lib/grub/x86_64-efi --boot-directory=/mnt/boot /dev/sda`

Note that the `-d` flag is mandatory, as otherwise, grub tries to use `/usr/lib/grub/i386-pc` from the rescue image, which does not contain the correct stuff.

Yayy! My system is now bootable again!

Comment: This saved my day

Comment: Just wanted to mention that when you run `fdisk -l` you'll likely see a Linux File System partition and a separate EFI partition.

What you should do then is:
1. Mount your Linux FS partition under `/mnt`
2. Mount your EFI partition under `/mnt/boot/efi`
3. Run what Linas suggested and remember to use your **Linux FS** partition in the final part of the command, ie: `grub-install -d /mnt/usr/lib/grub/x86_64-efi --boot-directory=/mnt/boot <linux FS partition>`

Answer (score 5):

Grub rescue mode can be treated as

```
set root=(hd0,gpt6)
set prefix=(hd0,gpt6)/boot/grub
insmod normal
normal
```

Once you login, enter `sudo update-grub && sudo grub-install /dev/sda`.

Comment: Should the `grub-install` not the done before the `update-grub`?

Comment: when I typed the first command, I got "_bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('_"

Comment: @Another.Chemist: the commands given should go to the GRUB interactive console, I think. That would be before the kernel boots. Your error looks like you have typed the commands into Bash.

Answer (score -4):

```
sudo apt-get --purge autoremove  grub-efi-amd64-signed
```

Comment: Welcome to the site, and thank you for your contribution. Would you mind adding some explanation on why/how this would solve the OPs problem?

Comment: Welcome to Unix & Linux! [Brevity is acceptable, but fuller explanations are better](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer).