# "Unable to install GRUB in /dev/sda" fatal error when reinstall ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, partition, grub, reinstall

I have recently tried to reinstall Ubuntu to my Lenovo X1 Carbon but I'm getting the following issues (all my data is backed up):

- I tried installing ubuntu from live disk. I selected "reinstall" and followed the default settings to the end where I got the following error:

```
unable to install GRUB in /dev/sda
Executing `grub-install /dev/sda` failed.
This is a fatal error.
```

- Since I had problems with my previous version I thought these may have transferred in the reinstall so I then tried `Erase Ubuntu 14 and replace with Ubuntu 20`. This gave me to same error.
  I tried following the suggestions on this post: https://askubuntu.com/questions/459620/unable-to-install-grub-in-dev-sda-when-installing-grub namely:
- Manually deleting the previous partition and creating a new one. This gave the same error.
- Installing grub via the boot terminal and via the terminal inside `Try Ubuntu`. Using `sudo grub-install /dev/sdb` and `sudo grub-install /dev/sda` In both instances I got

```
$ grub-install /dev/sda
grub-install: error: cannot find EFI directory.
```

So following advice from here [Cannot find EFI directory: issue with grub-install](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/405472/cannot-find-efi-directory-issue-with-grub-install) I mounted the efi system. Now when I use `sudo grub-install /dev/sdb` I get the error:

```
sudo grub-install /dev/sda
Install for x86_64-efi platform
grub-install: error: failed to get canonical path of `cow'.
```

- Returning to forum searches for this error I tried following the advice here https://askubuntu.com/questions/254491/failed-to-get-canonical-path-of-cow. When I try: `grub-install --recheck --root-directory=/mnt /dev/sda` I get:

```
sudo grub-install --recheck --root-directory=/mnt /dev/sda
Install for x86_64-efi platform
grub-install: error: cannot find EFI directory.
```

- So I go back to the error search and find a similar post here: [Cannot find EFI directory: issue with grub-install](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/405472/cannot-find-efi-directory-issue-with-grub-install)
  This time I try `grub-install --efi-directory=/dev/sda7` and I get:

```
grub-install --efi-directory=/dev/sda7
Installing x86_64-efi platform
grub-install: error: failed to get canonical path of `udev`.
```

- Advice from here https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=240818 so I then use `grub-install --efi-directory=/boot` which gives

```
sudo grub-install /dev/sda
Install for x86_64-efi platform
grub-install: error: failed to get canonical path of `cow'.
```

Which is the same error I got before so it seems like I've gone round in circles.

I've tried running boot-repair both from within TryUbuntu and via a live disk. These executed successfully but then when I restarted and tried to access Ubuntu I got the same errors as before.

I know that each of these has their own forums but I feel like I'm going round in circles between them all. Can anyone piece together each of the errors to help me?

Some background- The reason I'm reinstalling is that a few years ago my laptop crashed in the middle of an update (I hadn't realised the battery cable had been switch off.). My friend kindly spent an afternoon manually fixing parts to get it to work again. Since then there have been a few things I've not been able to get working properly (printer drivers and calendar syncing for example). Since these weren't a problem for my research I continued without them until the end of my PhD. I recently had some errors trying to use Firedrake. Since I've now finished my PhD it seemed like a safe time to back up all my data and reinstall Ubuntu. Hoping that the reinstall would rectify the problems from the previous crash.

Comment: If using Ubuntu's Ubquity installer, you have to have an ESP on the first drive, probably your sda. https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubiquity/+bug/1396379  You can reinstall grub, but if not familar, Boot-Repair and Advanced mode to choose ESP on sdb may be easier.  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair & https://sourceforge.net/p/boot-repair/home/Home/  You have to mount at minimum / (root) & ESP, to manually reinstall grub. Or full chroot. UEFI chroot, 
http://askubuntu.com/questions/53578/can-i-install-in-uefi-mode-with-the-alternate-installer/57380#57380

Comment: Thank you @oldfred it seems me error was coming from trying to use the EFI mode installation on a MBR system. So I was going round in circles trying to reinstall things that in the end weren't compatible. 

I've included a lengthy answer with what eventually worked after my friend managed to diagnose the source of the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I'm following up on my own question with how we managed to get things to work.

Turns out the root of the problem was the installation was in EFI but the system was in MBR.
Check this by attempting to boot with legacy only in the BIOS settings. if this doesn't work then this is your problem.

What we did to fix this.

- Changed BIOS back to both.
  Rebooted with the live drive then access terminal via Try Ubuntu.
- Followed the instructions here:
  https://polarclouds.co.uk/mbr-gpt-no-data-loss/ When you run the gdisk command there should be an MBR partition and a damaged GPT partition.
- reboot (with live drive access terminal again via Try Ubuntu)
- check the type has changed using `sudo fdisk -l`.
  It should now be type:GPT instead of type:dos.

Now reinstall. I got a partitioning error with reinstall but erase and reinstall worked.

Comment: The only time to use MBR(msdos) partitioning is, if using Windows in BIOS boot mode. But Microsoft has required vendors to install in UEFI boo tmode to gpt partitioned drives since 2012. So few systems are really BIOS anymore (But vendors often still call UEFI as BIOS).. I have used gpt with BIOS systems starting in 2010, so if no Windows you can use gpt with Ubuntu whether UEFI or BIOS. And if you were installing in UEFI mode, you have UEFI system as the installer would not even boot in UEFI mode with a BIOS only system.

Comment: @oldfred The laptop was set up in 2016 by my old university. It was set up with MBR partitioning. I can't voucher for why this was done but it was. I just discovered this when trying to reinstalling the system recently.

Comment: This solved my issue exactly. Thanks so much for following up on your own thread!